# How do I use django_tables2 with a filter?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm displaying data on a webpage, and I would like to migrate this code to use the table I created in tables.py. I can't figure out how to do it without breaking the filter.

views.py

```
def PlatListView(request):
    
    queryset = Plat.objects.all().values('id', 'description','status', 'phase__number','phase','schedule_found').annotate(lot_count=Sum('phase__lot_count')).order_by('description')

    f = PlatFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
   
    return render(request, 'blog/filtertable2.html', {'filter': f})
```

filters.py

```
class PlatFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    community = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Community.objects.all())
```

tables.py

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class PlatTable(tables.Table):  

    id = tables.Column()
    description = tables.Column()
    status = tables.Column()
    phase__number = tables.Column()
    lot_count = tables.Column()
    schedule_found = tables.Column()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = 'description'
        #model = Plat
```

filtertable2.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

<form method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
 {% for obj in filter.qs %}
  <tr>
    
        <td> {{ obj.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.status }}</td>
   
  </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
   
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: How do you render the template? Can you provide the relevant parts of the template?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added the html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your view you construct the table with the data from the filter:

```
def PlatListView(request):
    queryset = Plat.objects.annotate(
        lot_count=Sum('phase__lot_count')
    ).order_by('description')

    f = PlatFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    table = PlatTable(data=f.qs)
    return render(request, 'blog/filtertable2.html', {'filter': f, 'table': table})
```

You can then render the table with:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

{% render_table table %}
   
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: got it, thanks. And how do I Include the filter in the template?

Comment: @MattWilson: the same way as before. Forgot about that. Updated the answer.

Comment: @MattWilson: also made a typo in the view, `filter` of course still refers to `f`, not `f.qs`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any particular reason for using Values QuerySet, ie `values()`. You can simply annotate the value with queryset:

```
def plat_list_view(request):  # using snake_case when defining a method name.
    queryset = Plat.objects.annotate(lot_count=Sum('phase__lot_count')).order_by('description')
    f = PlatFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    return render(request, 'blog/filtertable2.html', {'filter': f})
```