# Display unique records in a django table

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have three models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    minit = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_owner = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dos_from = models.DateField()
    dos_to = models.DateField()

class Review(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='review_rel')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dos= models.DateField()
    review_type= models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

Some members will have no reviews at all, some will have multiple reviews even within the same project.

I would like to create a table with one row per member and project for the members who are assigned a review.

When I start with the Review model, I get multiple rows for the same member (if the member has more than one review within the same project) I don’t know how to dedup it.

```
import django_tables2 as tables

class Reviews_Table(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = (
                "project__project_name",
                "member__person_id",
                "member__first_name",
                "member__last_name",
                "member__minit",
                "member__dob",
                )
```

I also tried starting with the Member Model, but I can’t figure out how to go backwards and link to the Review model.

I have been stuck on this for a while. I would truly appreciate help.

Thank you

Comment: Intial suggestion, if your duped values are actually dupes, then run `distinct()` on the queryset. To alter the queryset, there are answers that offer solutions, as example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65428701/8382028